# Gatling test with multiple unique IP addresses

Tags: monitoring, load-testing, gatling

I have a *Gatling* load test that does a huge call to a webservice, and I can get response time information nicely, the problem is that all calls are done as a single user, thus cannot see the amount of concurrent users from *Jennifer5* monitoring tool. I've searched but couldn't find a way to make multiple unique IP users to call this webservice, thus showing me the amount of concurrent users in the monitoring tool, however approximate that value would be.

I've found this [page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gatling/-pSV27DMvE0/jdEfpHQ941AJ) but this does not work at all, what should I do? I do not wish to switch to *JMeter* now, even though I think it does have this capability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [forum you are referring to](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gatling/-pSV27DMvE0/jdEfpHQ941AJ)

> Note that, of course, you won't be able to do IP spoofing, but only use valid IP aliases.

So given your Scala code is correct you must have all the simulated IP addresses present in your operating system. Theres is a possibility to have more than one IP address on a physical network interface via [IP aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing), refer to your operating system documentation in order to learn how set additional addresses up. You may also find [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) guide interesting